# Higher order functions in haskell error

Tags: haskell

```
selectMenu :: Int->IO() 
selectMenu num
        |(num==1)=convertFromDecimal
        |(num==2)=--menu2
        |(num==3)=putStrLn("3")
        |(num==4)=putStrLn("4")
        |(num==5)=putStrLn("5")


convertFromDecimal:: IO()
convertFromDecimal= do 
            putStrLn("\n\tConvert From Decimal To Binary & Octals \n")
            putStrLn("----------------------------------------------------------\n")
            putStrLn("Enter 5 decimal numbers [,,] : ")
            input<-getLine
            let n=(read input)::[Int] -- is this right?
            --putStrLn (show n)
            let result = convertionTO decToOct n
            putStrLn(show result)`



decToOct :: Int -> [Int]
decToOct x = reverse(decToOct' x)
            where
        decToOct' 0 = []
        decToOct' y = let (a,b) = quotRem y 8 in [b] ++ decToOct' a




convertionTO :: (Int -> [Int] -> [Int]) -> [Int] -> [Int]
convertionTO _ [] = []  
convertionTO f (x:xs) = f x : convertionTO f xs
```

I correct those mistakes. I did update the question after correcting those errors. But this time it gives this error
How can i fix this error?

```
Assignment.hs:49:51:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Int] -> [Int]'
                with actual type `[Int]'
    Expected type: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
      Actual type: Int -> [Int]
    In the first argument of `convertionTO', namely `decToOct'
    In the expression: convertionTO decToOct n
Assignment.hs:66:25:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int'
                with actual type `[Int] -> [Int]'
    In the return type of a call of `f'
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `f x'
    In the expression: f x : convertionTO f xs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm copying the errors here in case you edit the question again.)

The first error

```
Assignment.hs:49:51:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Int] -> [Int]'
                with actual type `[Int]'
    Expected type: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
      Actual type: Int -> [Int]
    In the first argument of `convertionTO', namely `decToOct'
    In the expression: convertionTO decToOct n
```

refers to this line of code

```
            let result = convertionTO decToOct n
```

`conversionTO` expects its first argument to have the type `Int -> [Int] -> [Int]`, but `decToOct` instead has the type `Int -> [Int]`.

The second error

```
Assignment.hs:66:25:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int'
                with actual type `[Int] -> [Int]'
    In the return type of a call of `f'
    In the first argument of `(:)', namely `f x'
    In the expression: f x : convertionTO f xs
```

refers to this line of code

```
convertionTO f (x:xs) = f x : convertionTO f xs
```

`convertionTO` produces an `[Int]`, so the first argument to `:` must be an `Int`. But `f x` instead has type `[Int] -> [Int]`.

How to fix these?

I'm going to assume that your line 49 is correct, and that the type signature for `convertionTO` is wrong. In that case it should be

```
convertionTO :: (Int -> [Int]) -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

This doesn't fix the second error, as `f x` now has type `[Int]`.

The problem here is your use of `:`. `:` joins a single element to the start of a list. What you have is two lists that you want to join together. For this, use `++`.

```
convertionTO f (x:xs) = f x ++ convertionTO f xs
```

Finally, note that your `convertionTO` is in the standard library as [`concatMap`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3aconcatMap), which combines [`map`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3amap) with [`concat`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3aconcat).

Answer (score 1):

Those errors mean that you're referring to functions which don't exist. Either because you mistyped their names, or because you haven't defined them yet.

For example, instead of `showresult`, you probably meant `show result`, and I think you meant `decToOct'` instead of `decToAny'`. I can't see any references to `convertToDecimal` anywhere in the code you posted, so that error is probably somewhere else.

Comment: @code4Fun As you found hammar's answer useful, you should upvote it (click the up arrow by the left of the answer).